# Prove that if $A$ is null and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous derivative, then $f(A)$ is null

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

I have been doing this exercise and I would like to try this myself but I don't know where to begin.

The question asks to show that if $A$ is null and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous derivative, then $f(A)$ is $null$. Someone has already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137054/prove-that-if-a-is-null-and-f-mathbbr-longrightarrow-mathbbr-has-a-c) but there are no answers in that thread and the hints written there are not helpful with my current understanding. Facts that I noticed is that if I consider $A\subseteq [0,1]$ then $f'$ must be bounded on $[0,1]$. The comment by Nicholas Still on the attached thread suggests something similar but how does the boundedness of image of the derivative of the function $f$ help when talking about measures?

To give context, we have only started reading about outer measures and Lebesgue measures and I believe this exercise only involves only those topics. Another comment in the attached thread suggests using the idea of absolute continuous functions, but I haven't come across them so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic idea. Consider an interval $(s,t)$. $f(s,t) \subseteq [m,M]$ where $m$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum  of $f$ on $[s,t]$. If $m=f(x)$ and $M=f(y)$ then  $M-m \leq C |y-x| \leq C(t-s)$ where $C$ is a bound for $|f'|$. [This follows by MVT]. Hence the measure of $f(s,t)$ does not exceed $C$ times the measure of $(s,t)$.

Now use the fact that any null set can be covered by  sequence of open intervals with total length less than  $\epsilon$.